# @spawn parallel execution time

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am relatively new to parallel computing and was familiarizing myself with the @spawn macro.
From what I understand, @spawn assigns a process to a unique worker (unlike the case of @async).

I am on a system with 2 cores and I executed the following program:

```
addprocs(2)
@time @sync for i in 2:nprocs()
    @spawn for i in 1:10
        sleep(1);
    end
end

> 12.710672 seconds
```

I was expecting the execution time to be around **20 seconds** since the core is kept busy by worker 1 for 10 seconds, then worker 2 is assigned to the core and executes for another 10 seconds. It seems that both the tasks/workers are assigned to the same core and executed in parallel using multithreading?

Comment: What value do you get for Threads.nthreads() ?